# How to resolve React Native 0.73.3 issues with Apple M3 Pro?

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, mobile

Can't seem to get past this issue with React Native and Xcode 15.1:

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Here is the result of `react-native info`:

```
> npx react-native info                                                           ~/Sites/personalmap/hikebikemapper

  WARNING: You should run npx react-native@latest to ensure you're always using the most current version of the CLI. NPX has cached version (0.73.3) != current release (0.73.4)

info Fetching system and libraries information...
(node:5009) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
System:
  OS: macOS 14.2.1
  CPU: (11) arm64 Apple M3 Pro
  Memory: 226.25 MB / 18.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 21.5.0
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.21
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 10.2.4
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.01.22.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.15.2
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.2
      - iOS 17.2
      - macOS 14.2
      - tvOS 17.2
      - watchOS 10.2
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2023.1 AI-231.9392.1.2311.11330709
  Xcode:
    version: 15.1/15C65
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 17.0.9
    path: /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@17/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.7.6
    path: /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.6/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.73.3
    wanted: 0.73.3
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: false
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: false
  newArchEnabled: false

info React Native v0.73.4 is now available (your project is running on v0.73.3).
```

I've cleared out `node_modules`, `Pods`, the lock files, derived data, cleaned build folder, restarted, and am now out of ideas. Please help.

- Deleted `node_modules` and reinstalled with `yarn`
- Deleted `Pods` folder and lock file and ran `pod install`
- Tried excluding `arm64` Architecture in Xcode
- Read Firebase documentation (is this Firebase related?)

System info:

```
> ruby --version
ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [arm64-darwin23]
> node --version
v21.5.0
> pod --version
1.15.2
> java --version
openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.9+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.9+0, mixed mode, sharing)
> brew --version
Homebrew 4.2.7
```